# Correct use of REST api StatusCodes when not finding requested entities

Tags: httprequest, rest, http-status-codes

I have hosted a database and a RESTful API, but have been wondering what StatusCode to return when someone tries to query non-existant entities.

I found myself wondering 2 different cases not knowing what StatusCode to return:

**Case A)** When someone tries to /api/user/15448, when that user does not exist.
I understand it should be in the 4xx range since it would be a Client error, but found alot of conflicting info regarding the following StatusCodes:

```
1. 400 Bad Request
```

Some people suggest using this, but I see more voices in argumenting this is **too broad/vague**.

```
2. 404 Not Found
```

Here it seems more appropriate since the entity was 'Not Found' when querying the database through the api request. However this also gets used/returned on not found routes etc and **might cause confusion** again.

```
3. 412 Precondition Failed
```

This one seems interesting to me aswell since it specifies "The client has indicated preconditions in its headers which the server does not meet.".
While you COULD argue the preconditions ARE MET (15448 is a valid number atleast), it can also be argued that these preconditions should be valid requests for returning existing entities.

**Case B)** When someone tries to /api/users/getByZipcode?zipCode=4454, when this particular zipCode does not contain any users.
Do I return '200 OK' with an additional message on stating the request was valid but returned no users?

At first I thought about using:

```
  204 No Content
```

But quickly found out this is practically only used in updating larger resources where you do not want to send back large data just to confirm a succesfull update.

Any tips on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For case (B), I think the right perspective is to think of this as a REST query, where the caller doesn't know how but a result set they're about to get.  In such cases, people often have the REST response paginated: (1) they return the first N, (2) they tell the user what the total number of records in the response will be, and (3) they accept an extra query param that specified what position to start at (default 0).  That way, the user can keep calling this same call, getting a different page of the answer each time.  The total count can be a response parameter.

Comment: For case (A), I would return 404, too :-).

Comment: @moilejter Thanks for responding!
For your case (b) response, this seems to be a good way to go about it for a succesful request with data, the case however has 0 users in that zipcode but there was nothing wrong with the request, it would just return an empty array or list of users.
Would you also catch this as a 404 or a 200 OK with additional info?

Comment: I would have said 200 OK with additional info (total count = 0) and an empty list in the body, as you said...